# Table border adding 1px in the corner of each TD

Tags: html, css

I have a table that when I use `border-collapse:collapse;` it shows a single 1px in the border of the row coming from the following row. Any ideas how I can fix that?

I want it to look exactly like that without any padding between the cells or anything.

This is in Firefox by the way, I haven't tried other browsers.

[Here is my JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/un8pr8hv/2/)

[image: 1px in corner]

HTML / CSS

```css
.responsive-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive-table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.resp-content,
.resp-div {
  background: #eee;
}
.responsive-table thead th,
.basic-table thead th {
  background: #006bb2;
  color: #fff;
}
.responsive-table th {
  border: 1px solid #0087e0;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks fine in Chrome. It might just have to do with the way Firefox renders it

Comment: I need it to work in all modern browsers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a rendering issue. At 2px the problem still shows, but if you set either border to 0px the problem disappears. Proof is that Chrome renders it fine.

Comment: It makes sense that it's a rendering problem, but surely there is a way to fix it... or a work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increase the lower border width of the table header:

```
.responsive-table th {
    border: 1px solid #0087e0;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```css
.responsive-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive-table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.resp-content,
.resp-div {
  background: #eee;
}
.responsive-table thead th,
.basic-table thead th {
  background: #006bb2;
  color: #fff;
}
.responsive-table th {
  border: 1px solid #0087e0;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

Alternatively, `border-bottom-style: double;` will specify, as the name suggests, a double border:

```
.responsive-table th {
    border: 1px solid #0087e0;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

```css
.responsive-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive-table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.resp-content,
.resp-div {
  background: #eee;
}
.responsive-table thead th,
.basic-table thead th {
  background: #006bb2;
  color: #fff;
}
.responsive-table th {
  border: 1px solid #0087e0;
  border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Screenshot]

More information: [Border conflict resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution)

Comment: glad to hear it! go CSS

Comment: `border: 1px 2px solid #0087e0` is invalid.

Comment: @Oriol - I assume he meant border-bottom: 2px solid #0087eo or something like that. Anyway, you should edit out that first part and just leave the border-bottom-style part.

Comment: @FirstLegion - If you're interested in why this works, [here are the border conflict rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution). Either Chrome or Firefox is implementing the rules in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo-elements to cover it up:

```
.responsive-table thead th:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #0087e0;
}
```

Just change the color of the border to whatever matches. You could also use a `:before` to cover up the far left side's blemish.

Comment: That seems to get rid of the border. Can you post it in the JSFiddle?